# Close processing is slow, in elasticsearch's TransportClient. I want to quickly

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

- Question

  1. Do I need TransportClient's close processing?
  2. Is there a way to speed up TransportClient's close processing?
- context
  I am doing performance tuning.
  TransportClient's close processing is slow.
  I am in trouble very much.
  I measured.
  It took 2000 ms by close processing.

## code

```
public SearchResponse search(SearchParam param) {

    EsConnection connect = new EsConnection();
    TransportClient client = connect.getTransportClient();

    try {
        long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        response = client.prepareSearch()
                .setSize(param.getNum())
                .setFrom(param.getFrom())
                .setQuery(shouldQuery)
                .execute()
                .actionGet(timeoutMsec);
        System.out.println(response);
        long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.err.println("search:"   + (end1 - start1) + "ms");

    } catch (ElasticsearchException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        client.close();
        long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.err.println("close:"   + (end1 - start1) + "ms");
    }

    return response;
}
```

## Environment

- Language: Java 8
- Framework: Spring
- Elasticsearch client (jar) ver

  - org.elasticsearch: 5.1.1
  - org.elasticsearch.client: 5.1.1
- Elasticsearch's ver: 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

It's problem in the design of network library Netty4.
Look issue [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2084)
and commit who introduce close method into Elasticsearch client [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/c08557d033b9ce67613c99abaa9e5082119a6160#diff-444b2abb975d5169f06bf12d1e3f6a08)

For my opinion design of GlobalEventExecutor in Netty4 very bad and you can't speed up performance.